# Github API - information about technologies used in a repository

Tags: github, web-crawler, github-api

I'm building an application that's supposed to crawl through Github repositories. I know that there's a `languages` property that github supports, but I'd like to crawl for a little more insight - frameworks used would be cool, maybe architecture (I know, this is a long shot).

A perfect feature would be something like StackOverflow tags.

I think that parsing actual files would be an overkill for the task, I don't know if I wanna put in so much effort, since it's a hobby project, not a commercial one.

Do you know of any feature that could help me with my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search by [`topics`](https://github.com/blog/2309-introducing-topics) which are tags added by user specifying the technology or the type of project.

You can also filter by topics when using the [search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/), an example to search for `rails` and `ruby` topics :

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json" \
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:ruby+topic:rails
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted! Too bad it's a realatively new feature, since many repositories will not be tagged with this property.